# How to retrieve HTML form values?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a simple form and would like to reflect the values in the new page upon submission. I tried using javascript to do so. However, was not successful as it did not print out. Can someone help me please? Also, I am open to ideas which are simpler since javascript might not be the only way to do this. PHP seems tough for me.

This is my form.

```
<head>
</head> 
<body>
<form action="demo_form.html" method="POST">
First Name<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the html page after submission which is also "demo_form.html"

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var nameValue = document.getElementById("fname").value;
document.getElementById("printHere").value=nameValue;
</script>
</head>
<body>
Welcome <div id="printHere"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need of JS here, you can do this by php. You have already defined `post`method for your data

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how JS/HTML works. The previous page is already lost and forgotten. Either use a server-side language or change the method to GET so you can pick the values from the URL.

Comment: could you give me an example of how php can be used here? i tried doing it. but it doesnt print out the results. i added the following line: <?php echo $_POST['fname'];?>

Comment: The easiest way to pass data between web pages is to stay on the same page -- hide the second page content in a div that gets displayed after successful login. Show and hide divs on the same page, and avoid creating a lot of web pages and passing data around among them.

Answer (score 1):

---

### Note

---

Save your page with php extension instead of html (You have used demo_form.html in form action )

Remove JS and just include this on top

```
    if(isset($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);   //Retreive your data as required
}
```

Final Code

```
<body>
<?php
        if(isset($_POST)){
        print_r($_POST);   //Retreive your data as required
    }
?>
<form action="demo_form.php" method="POST">
First Name<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't forget PHP's opening and closing tags. `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: thanks for this. it still doesn't work. must the form be in php? or just the response page be in php will do? how do i edit 'print_r($_POST)' according to the data i want to retrieve?

Comment: You are using same page. So it must be in php, or you have 2 pages? @mrghost1988

Comment: @Deadlock do you mean I can have one php page with the form? Once submitted, it will return to the same page with the updated welcome screen? Meaning if user fills up his first name, upon submission, the new page will already have his first name on the welcome page(which is the one with the form he previously filled)?

Comment: I was confused when you asked that `just response page be in php`. Your data will be in corresponding name as defined in form. Like First name will be in `$_POST['fname']` and so on

Answer (score 1):

The post variables are related to the "name" attributes of your form elements.

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' />
```

This will be avalable after submit in your post array by

$`_POST['firstname'];`

To catch it, it is best practice to see if it is set first.

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) {
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
}
```

You place that at the very top of your page, even before the doctype.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['firstname']) {
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
}

?>
```

Now you can print the value by "echo" your variable.

```
Hello <?php echo $firstname; ?> to this page;
```

Your page must have the *.php extension.

**EDIT: added info for help and learning purpose**

To suit the fields in your own application, you change the name of "firstname" to the "name" attribute of your input field, ie "fname".

To add more fields.

```
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){$fname = $_POST['fname']; }
if(isset($_POST['lname'])){$lname = $_POST['lname']; }
if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email = $_POST['email']; }
```

It will be interesting for you to see how the $_POST array looks like. In your php tags at the very top and at the beginning, add this:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($_POST); // can also do var_dump($_POST);, just try it
echo "</pre>";
```

You will be presented with the array and you can see its structure.

Comment: thanks. this doesnt work. according to my example, i am using fname. how does this change? must the code be included in the form page or the response page? i haven't tried php before and would like to learn. thank you.

Comment: Hi, you should change the "firstname" to the name of your "name"-attribute of the html input tag in your form.

Answer (score 1):

POST data is data that is handled server side. And Javascript is on client side. you should use GET method. and in the demo_form.html use this js code to recieve the parameters:

```
var params = getUrlParams();
var first_name = params.fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out using javascript:

1st html form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="profile">
        <form action="demo_form.html" method="GET">
            First Name<input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

demo_form.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Loaddata() {
            // Get data from query string & create an array
            var vars = {};
            var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            });

            document.getElementById("printHere").innerHTML = vars["fname"];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Loaddata();">
    Welcome
    <div id="printHere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```